# How can I fix the table are not connect together

Tags: html

How can I solve the problem and what is my mistake in the code?
Can someone help me with this problem and explain the reason to help me understand more, please?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9BZW.jpg

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img src="img/n20logo.jpg" width="872" height="215">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="img/n20bg.jpg" width="200">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px;">
            <img src="img/n20vista.jpg"/>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px;">
            <img src="img/n20wall.jpg" width="200">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px;">
            <img src="img/n20contact.jpg" width="200">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h2>Flowers</h2>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h2>Landscaping</h2>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h2>Walled gardens</h2>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h2>Contact us</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>Olde Worlde Gardens specialise in preserving plant species from our past. All our stock has been seen in gardens for over 200 years. We use no modern cross pollination techniques to produce the hybrid that are currently taking over our gardens and do not use any genetically modified species. If you wish to experience the plants and gardens of yesteryear, visit our extensive nurseries.
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h3><b>Web page last updated by:</b> Philip Housden zz*** ****</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: I recommend not using a `<table>` unless you are working with tabular data. Modern web has many alternatives when it comes to layouting a page, as you are doing.

Comment: Please explain what the exact problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `<p>Olde Worlde Gardens specialise in preserving plant species from our past. All our stock has been seen in gardens for over 200 years. We use no modern cross pollination techniques to produce the hybrid that are currently taking over our gardens and do not use any genetically modified species. If you wish to experience the plants and gardens of yesteryear, visit our extensive nurseries.</p>` is a big element.

You need to give it a width and then try a `word-wrap` css property.